# Flexbox item won't align to flex-end

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Trying to get this codepen to work w/ `.inner-wrp` div (dark red) tucking in under the lightblue `.top-right` div.

https://codepen.io/Troop4Christ/pen/oPwqGV

```css
.purple {
  background: purple;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}

.lightblue {
  background: lightblue;
}

.darkred {
  background: darkred;
}

.lightbrown {
  background: lightbrown;
}

.orange {
  background: orange;
}

.outer-wrp {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.outer-wrp .left-side {
  height: 100%;
  width: 500px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.outer-wrp .top-right {
  width: calc(100vw - 500px);
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 90px;
}
.outer-wrp .inner-wrp {
  width: calc(100% - 500px);
  display: block;
  height: calc(100% - 90px);
  float: right;
}
.outer-wrp .inner-wrp .inner-left {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-wrp purple">
  <div class="left-side green"></div>
  <div class="top-right lightblue"></div>
  <div class="inner-wrp darkred">
    <div class="inner-left brown"></div>
    <div class="inner-right orange"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

I have `align-self: flex-end` on the `.inner-wrp`, but it's still going under the green `.left-side` div.

How do I get it to move over to the right under the light blue div?

Comment: you want that dark red to move to the right and stay last one at the bottom ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing a lot of properties (flex, inline-block, float, vertical-align, etc) which is useless as you only need to rely on flexbox properties. You are also using `vw` unit which is not good as it contains the scrollbar width and may lead to unwanted behavior when there is scroll (use 100% instead). Then what you want can be done with a column direction not a row direction:

```css
.purple {
  background: purple;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}

.lightblue {
  background: lightblue;
}

.darkred {
  background: darkred;
}

.lightbrown {
  background: lightbrown;
}

.orange {
  background: orange;
}

.outer-wrp {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.outer-wrp .left-side {
  height: 100%;
  width: 500px;
}

.outer-wrp .top-right {
  width: calc(100% - 500px);
  height: 90px;
}

.outer-wrp .inner-wrp {
  width: calc(100% - 500px);
  height: calc(100% - 90px);
  display:flex;
}

.outer-wrp .inner-wrp .inner-right {
  width: 200px;
}
.outer-wrp .inner-wrp .inner-left {
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
}

body {
 margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-wrp purple">
  <div class="left-side green"></div>
  <div class="top-right lightblue"></div>
  <div class="inner-wrp darkred">
    <div class="inner-left brown"></div>
    <div class="inner-right orange"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That was it! Thanks! Now to just wrap my mind around the "why" that worked.. lol!

Comment: @RavenHursT it's easy, switch to column, so it's from top to bottom ;) and no more from left to right ... so the overflow will make the element to start in the new column not new row

Comment: Yup.. the just clicked for me a few seconds ago.. thanks the breadcrumb @temani-afif

Just in case anyone's interested.. the solution: https://codepen.io/Troop4Christ/pen/qMjYLa?editors=1100

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your desired output correctly, you'll want to create a container `<div>` for the red and blue containers, and give it the following:

```
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
align-items: flex-start;
height: 100%;
width: 50%;
```

This can be seen **[here](https://codepen.io/Obsidian-Age/pen/jvwxZe?editors=1100)**.

And compiled in the following:

```css
.purple {
  background: purple;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}

.lightblue {
  background: lightblue;
}

.darkred {
  background: darkred;
}

.brown {
  background: brown;
}

.orange {
  background: orange;
}

.outer-wrp {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.outer-wrp .left-side {
  height: 100%;
  width: 500px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.outer-wrp .top-right {
  width: calc(100vw - 500px);
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 90px;
}

.outer-wrp .inner-wrp {
  width: calc(100% - 500px);
  display: block;
  height: calc(100% - 90px);
  float: right;
}

.outer-wrp .inner-wrp .inner-left {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
  height: 100%;
}

.blue-red {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-wrp purple">
  <div class="left-side green"></div>
  <div class="top-right lightblue"></div>
  <div class="inner-wrp darkred">
    <div class="inner-left brown"></div>
    <div class="inner-right orange"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You may need to update `.outer-wrp .inner-wrp` to be `calc(100vw - 500px)`, or fiddle around a little from here to suit your needs.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid adding another wrapper.  I was hoping to use flexbox to avoid that.

If I added another wrapper, I could most definitely accomplish this w/o using flexbox at all:

https://codepen.io/Troop4Christ/pen/aawGQv?editors=1100